# How to apply styles conditionally inside multiple id selection?

Tags: sass

how to apply styles conditionally inside multiple id selection in sass?

for eg. if there is following html file

// demo.html

```
 <div id="id1">
   <h1></h1>
 </div>
 <div id="id2">
   <h1></h1>
 </div>
 <div id="id3">
   <h1></h1>
 </div>
```

then I should be able to apply styles like following.

// styles.scss

```
#id1,
#id2,
#id3 {
  if(id1): apply red color to <h1>
  else: apply blue color to <h1> // ie to <h1>s inside id2 and id3 divs.

}
```

Comment: if(id1): Are you trying to check if the id1 exists here ?

Comment: all 3 ids are available, but apply one color if it's id1 and different color if other than id1. so checking which ID we are getting or have at that point. as you see in dom we have all 3 ids.

Comment: Take a look at my response below. SCSS can not check anything from Your HTML. You need to pass some variable to Your mixin and than SCSS will be able to make some conditional styling based on that passed parameter :)

Comment: Yeah, I have checked these if/else based on params, but trying to do as per existing ids on HTML, seems it's not possible. Anyway, thanks !

Comment: If its possible - Please mark the answer as the correct one / upvote :) have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

There is a if/else in scss. Check this out -> https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/if

However, I'm not sure if that's possible with SCSS only... Check the docs. You will see that the conditions are mostly based on the passed parameters

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a [each loop](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/each) instead of conditions? First you declare a list of the styles and then you loop over them to apply them:

```
$colors: ("1": red, "2": green, "3": blue);

@each $id, $color in $colors {
  #id#{$id} {
    color: $color;
  }
}
```

The first parameter is the key of the item in the list and the second one is the value. Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/Gh05d/pen/gOPMVeK) for you to play around with.